# Joining Multiple Rows From Within

Tags: php, mysql

**The Problem**

I have four tables I need to pull info from, two are just simple joins.

My query is returning nothing. Basically, there are forms I need to make sure I tied to my patient from one table, and the next table, to allow me to pull the form name so it's the correct form.

**What I have**

```
select person.first, person.last, treatmentPlan.created, treatmentPlan.updated, treatmentPlan.provider_id, intake.created, intake.updated, assesment.created, assesment.updated, discharge.created, discharge.updated

from form_patient_tie intake
LEFT OUTER JOIN form_patient_tie treatmentPlan ON intake.patient_id = treatmentPlan.patient_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN form_patient_tie assesment ON intake.patient_id = assesment.patient_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN form_patient_tie discharge ON intake.patient_id = discharge.patient_id

JOIN form as intakeForm ON intakeForm.form_id = intake.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN form treatmentPlanForm ON treatmentPlan.form_id = treatmentPlanForm.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN form assesmentForm on assesment.form_id = assesmentForm.form_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN form dischargeForm on discharge.form_id = dischargeForm.form_id
JOIN patient ON intake.patient_id = patient.patient_id
JOIN person on patient.person_id = person.person_id

WHERE (treatmentPlanForm.form_name LIKE "%Counseling Treatment Plan%" OR treatmentPlanForm.form_name IS NULL)
AND (intakeForm.form_name LIKE "%Counseling Intake%" OR intakeForm.form_name IS NULL)
AND (assesmentForm.form_name LIKE "%Counseling Assesment Review%" OR assesmentForm.form_name IS NULL)
AND (dischargeForm.form_name LIKE "%Counseling Discharge%" OR dischargeForm.form_name IS NULL)
```

It returns nothing even though I know there is a patient with Intake, Review, and Assessment done, but no discharge. If they have all 4, it works right, but if they are missing one, it doesn't.

It should look like

John  Doe  2013-01-13 2013-01-15 2013-02-13 etc. It's definitely allowed for them to be null as not every person will have one filled out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though your join to the "form" table (intakeForm alias) should also be a LEFT JOIN. Otherwise if there is not a match on the intake form, the entire query will return nothing.

Comment: I think one of your underlying assumptions is mistaken. Try removing all the LEFT JOINs (since they're optional) and you should be left with a fairly simple select on 3 tables. If the data exists as you say it does, it should return your result.